# How to save result from a GET request with OkHttp in a local variable?

Tags: android, get, okhttp

I'm trying to make a Get Request with OkHttp in Java. I made it successfully using asynchronous threads but I'm "stuck" Inside onResponse function. I mean, I can't use the result of the request anywhere else than in this function. How can I do to make this code work ?

```
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md")
                    .build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                        final String responseData = response.body().string();
                    LoginInscription.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.txtString);
                            tv.setText(responseData);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.txtString);
            String res = tv.getText().toString();

            System.out.println(res);
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure your 
`System.out.println(res);` might not work as scope of `final String res` ends before this.

You can declare a activity/class level variable/method which can be updated `onResponse()`.
For ex:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtString.setText(myResponse);
        }   
    });
}
```

Get more examples at:
https://www.journaldev.com/13629/okhttp-android-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks. And then I can assign the text from txtString to a variable and use it as I want ?

Comment: Exactly. Also you can call a method say `updateTextAndDoSomeFun(String text)` on http response.

Comment: I updated the code, but I still can't get the response in res. Can you tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure, `responseData` is not null/empty? Put a `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (String)responseData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` to see if it actually not null/empty. Also, can you debug in method `onResponse`, if to see your call reaches there.

Comment: Finally I made a second function and I called it from onResponse and passed responseData as a parameter. From the new function, I was able to assign the data to a member variable of my class. That's great, it's what I needed: to access to my data from where I want whenver I want. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great! Happy to see it working :) When you have multiple calls in same activity, you can use light UI threads to update variables/fields onResponse.